# KML Google Earth EC will not handle White Space in URL

Tags: url, kml, spaces

I have been racking my brain all morning trying to find a way to get Google Earth EC 5.2.1.1588 to allow me to link a folder on a network drive so that users can click on place marks and, if need be, open the corresponding folder containing data pertinent to that place mark.

The system works fine until a directory containing a white space is involved.  Unfortunately, the problematic directories are higher up the path (i.e. just off the root drive) and I cannot simply change the names as this would break an innumerable number of other links and shortcuts already in effect.

I have tried adding the %20 string to the white spaces within the KML but the system continues to fail to load the folder.  Otherwise, the KML can open any directory path that does not contain a white space (this is my only problem).

Sample snippet of code is:

```
<![CDATA[ <description> <a href>"M:\My Path"</a>Linked Folder</description> ]]>
```

Is there something else I might try?  Interestingly there is very little chatter about this and I suspect Google EC may be the culprit.

Comment: Could using a relative path work?  I could not possibly zip all of the data into a single KMZ but if a relative path can work outside of a KML maybe I can place the KML in a directory further along the path where the subsequent child directories contain no spaces.  How could this be done if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the HTML is wrong plus you should add the CDATA to inside the description element. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
  <Placemark>
    <description>
      <![CDATA[ <a href="M:\My Path\">Linked Folder</a> ]]>
    </description>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

This works as does `M:\My%20Path\` but realize that `M:\My Path\` is not a URL so an alternative would be "`file:///G:/My%20Path/`" which also works. Only works if the option "*Allow access to local files are personal data*" in Tools/Options is checked.

Also must make sure the "Show results in external browser" option is **unchecked** otherwise GE won't launch folder in windows explorer window. GE is a stickler for these things.

Comment: Alright - that got deleted.  I'll try again here.

Neither of these attempts worked.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
  <Placemark>
    <description>
      <![CDATA[ <a href="D:\test\New Folder\">Linked Folder</a> ]]>
    </description>
  </Placemark>
</kml>`

and

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
  <Placemark>
    <description>
      <![CDATA[ <a href=file:///"D:/test/New Folder/">Linked Folder</a> ]]>
    </description>
  </Placemark>
</kml>`

Comment: Additionally using the %20 string for the white space in either example does not resolve the issue.  Am I using the proper syntax?

Comment: Checked GE EC client and appears you need to make sure the "Show results in external browser" is unchecked otherwise won't launch folder in windows explorer window.

Comment: This worked using the `<a href="D:\test\New%20Folder\">Link Name</a>` method.  I couldn't get anything to happen using "file:///" and believe I'm using the wrong syntax.  Only issue is the GE browser tries to open but this is a small inconvenience for me.  So: Access Local Files = True, External Browser = False. Thanks.